# Is there option to bind multiple methods in one statement in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i was wondering if there is a way to bind multiple functions in one statement in React class constructor?
insted of:

```
this.function1.bind(this);
this.function2.bind(this);
this.function3.bind(this);
```

Comment: Use arrow functions instead of regular functions, so you don't need to bind anything.

Comment: 1. no 2. you don't have to bind if you use functional components or arrow functions: `function1 = () => { ... }` in your class (also note that React is just JS, so you could use something like `["function1", "function"].forEach(nm => this[nm].bind(this));`

Comment: I never did this but you can try this: `const self = this; [funcName1, funcName2].forEach(funcName => self[funcName].bind(self))`

Comment: Ok, when using arrow functions do i have to bind them if i pass them to other componets? I'm currently learning React and there is this: "Now the only thing we have to do is bind the method to this; we do that in the constructor method at the top of our component but below the super() call. The reason we have to bind the this keyword when passing a function to another component is that it needs to stay in the same context in which it was declared. Always remember: you must bind this for all methods in class components when passing them to other components."